# Is it possible to match user to the document in firebase console?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I was looking on the internet but I haven't found answear to my question.

I have two firebase collections: **measurement** and **users**. 
In **measurement** collection I'm creating documents with **{date, measure, decription and uid}**.
In user **collection** I have user documents **{first-name, last-name**}.
My question is that - Is it possible to make in  Security Rules code that user2 can't see documents created by user1 and user1 can't see documents created by user2?

---

I tried something like that:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Make sure to write security rules for your app before that time, or else
    // your app will lose access to your Firestore database
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2020, 3, 2);
    }
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

but there is an error - "Unhandled Rejection (FirebaseError): Missing or insufficient permissions." and my documents aren't rendering.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Give it a shot.

Comment: This type of use-case is specifically called out in the Firebase documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication. As Doug said, give it a shot and post back (with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) if you run into problems.